# Unnest a huge JSON array into individual JSON object

Tags: json, linux, unix, jq, jtc

I have the a single JSON object as below,

```
{
    "someOtherArray": [ {} , {} ],
    "a": [
        {
            "item1": "item1_value",
            "item2": "item2_value"
        },
        {
            "item1": "item1_value",
            "item2": "item2_value"
        },
        {
            ....
        },
        
        100 million more object
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to make each element in the array as a separate JSON object as below,

```
{ "a": { "item1": "item1_value", "item2": "item2_value" } }
{ "a": { "item1": "item1_value", "item2": "item2_value" } }
```

The raw files has millions of nested objects in a single JSON array, which I want to split into multiple individual JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a response to the revised question (i.e., "I just want 'a'").

You could just tweak the standard answer:

```
jq --stream -nc '
  {"a": fromstream(2|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0]=="a")) )}
'
```

---

#### Footnote: Execution Times

The jq streaming parser is economical with memory at the expense of execution speed.  If the input consists of an array of N small objects, then the execution time should very roughly be linear in N, and the memory requirements should be roughly constant.

To give some idea of what to expect, I created an array of 10^8 objects similar to those described in the Q. The file size was 4GB.  On a 3GHz machine, reading the file took about 16 minutes of u+s time, but the "peak memory footprint" was only 1.2MB.

gojq was slightly slower but required significantly more memory, the "peak memory footprint" being 8.4MB, and I suspect that the required memory grows with N.

Comment: Thank you sir! this works on small files like 200-400 MB it takes 5 mins, but for files like 2GB it just runs forever. I waited for 3 hours and killed it. I'm using a 16 core 64GB RAM machine with no other jobs in the background.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was testing your code with multiple file sizes to test the perf! Cheers!

Comment: Did you try gojq?  If the file is just 2GB there might be no need to use --stream at all on your 64GB machine ....

Comment: Yes, I have tested on jq and gojq and the they are near identical in perf. I have files starting from 2GB to 150 GB, so I wanted to test with the smallest one to save time. I do need the stream for the large ones. Cheers!

Comment: is jq stream the right approach for 150 GB files in your opinion? If yes, then si 16 core 64 GB hardware spec enough for such streaming command?

Comment: jq --stream with a 64GB computer should work with an arbitrarily large file of the type you've described, at least in principle.  Time should be roughly linear in the size of the file.  If you find otherwise, it might be the result of a bug or flaw. Not sure about gojq's memory management.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try the same using both jq and gojq. Appreciate your help  : )

Comment: Please see footnote re execution times.

Comment: Wow.. this is really interesting! thank you for such insights :)  So is there a buffersize which we can set/alter for streaming, which would take more resources but reduce the IO on read&write ?

Comment: Not sure, but I doubt that that's very important. The fact that the gojq execution time is much the same suggests that the work required to construct all the paths to all the atomic values is inherently time-consuming.

Comment: Yes that looks to be correct, which is weird for a stream reader!

Comment: Of course there are other "streaming" parsers for JSON out there, but  pypi.org/project/json-stream is much, much slower than jq or gojq.

Answer (score 1):

To process a huge file, possibly larger than what fits into the memory, you can break it down into pieces using the `--stream` directive. This stream can then be read sequentially using `inputs` in combination with the `--null-input` (or `-n`) flag. To achieve the overall effect of

```bash
jq '.a[]' file.json
```

you need to truncate the streamed parts by stripping off the first two levels of their structure information (essentially their location path: the outer object's `a` field, and the contained array's indices `[]`). Using `fromstream` will then reconstruct each entity once read in completely.

```bash
jq --stream -n 'fromstream(2 | truncate_stream(inputs))' file.json
```

```json
{
  "item1": "item1_value",
  "item2": "item2_value"
}
{
  "item1": "item1_value",
  "item2": "item2_value"
}
:
```

To create your final structure, re-create the resulting object with the output of `fromstream`, and use the `--compact-output` (or `-c`) option to have each object on its separate line:

```bash
jq --stream -nc '{a: fromstream(2 | truncate_stream(inputs))}' file.json
```

```json
{"a":{"item1":"item1_value","item2":"item2_value"}}
{"a":{"item1":"item1_value","item2":"item2_value"}}
:
```

---

If you also want the top-level field name (here `a`) be read in and re-created dynamically, you will have to construct your own stream truncation:

```bash
jq --stream -nc '
  fromstream(inputs | if first | has(2) then
    setpath([0]; first | del(.[1])),
    if has(1) then empty else map(.[:1]) end
  else empty end)
' file.json
```

```json
{"a":{"item1":"item1_value","item2":"item2_value"}}
{"a":{"item1":"item1_value","item2":"item2_value"}}
:
```

Comment: it takes around 3-4 hours to process 12 GB file. Is there a way to speed this up? Cheers!

Comment: Using the solution I posted separately, I found gojq to be faster by a factor of about 2.  Definitely worth a try.

Comment: @peak On a sidenote, I've seen you pretty active in the jq github community. Do you happen to know that they've discontinued it for good? I don't see a plan or discussion on the future releases of jq. But gojq on the other hand is getting equally if not better

Comment: @inian - "For good" is further than my crystal ball can see.  Unfortunately, gojq has some inherent deficiencies compared to jq, so I'm wondering whether there's anyone with the skills necessary to start a "fork" of jq if none of the existing "maintainers" is unwilling to pass the baton.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward "streaming" solution to the problem assuming the top-level key must be determined dynamically:

```
 < input.json jq -cn --stream '
  input as $in
  | $in[0][0] as $key
  | fromstream(2|truncate_stream($in,inputs))
  | {($key): .}
'
```

Comment: Thanks. So I've edited the json structure in the question. How can I skip some other field being streamed into this? I just want 'a' and want to ignore 'someOtherArray'. Cheers!!

Comment: After a question has been answered and accepted, it's usually better to avoid making a substantial change to the question, especially if the change means the accepted answer is no longer quite right.

Comment: Understood! I'll be cautious in the future : )